# Выполнение bash скрипта из php

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, bash

Я пытаюсь реализовать привязку домена к серверу средствами php и нескольких bash скриптов. В первом скрипте я устанавливаю домен в апач, во втором я устанавливаю на домен letsencrypt сертификат при помощи certbot'а. Из-под ssh под рутом все скрипты работают отлично.

Вот скрипт установки домена в апач:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName $1
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot $2
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
<Directory $2>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
" > "/etc/apache2/sites-available/$1.conf"

a2ensite $1

service apache2 restart
service apache2 status
```

Вот скрипт установки сертификата:

```
certbot --authenticator webroot --webroot-path $2 --installer apache -d $1 --redirect

service apache2 restart
service apache2 status
```

Вызываю из PHP я их примерно одинаково:

```
$result = exec(
    "'bwV32GnQXc66' | sudo -S " . $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/php/bash/add_domain.sh " . escapeshellcmd($value) . " " . $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],
    $output
);
```

И это не работает... Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста, или подскажите какой-то другой метод. Спасибо!

Comment: Это очень чревато ... проверяйте права пользователя, под которым запускается PHP скрипт.

Comment: Для справки, сейчас letsencrypt выпускает wildcard сертификаты, и проверка идет без размещения файла, а через доп запись в DNS. Плюс у них есть скрипт для этого. Код писать вообще не надо. Не понятно, зачем делаете свой велосипед?

Comment: @Total вопрос идет не о установке сертификата, а о выполнении bash скриптов из php, но все равно спасибо, я приму эту информацию к сведению!

Comment: @aleksandr спасибо, я сделал как в посте и решил проверить через sudo, запустил из-под юзера www-data. Скрипт запустился, но не хватило прав на создание файла, видимо. Если это решится, то, думаю, все заработает